# Tying an object to a block

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

I have the following object:

```
Someobject *Object = [[Someobject alloc] init];

void (^Block)() = ^()
{
    Use(Object);
};

DoSomethingWith(Block);
```

The block is copied in `DoSomethingWith` and stored somewhere. it might either not be called, called once or called multiple times. I want to tie `Object` with the block so whenever the block or any of its copies is released, `Object` is released, and whenever the block or any of its copies is retained or copied, `Object` will be retained.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your first line to `[[[Someobject alloc] init] autorelease]` and you're done.

Blocks retain objects declared without and referenced within their body, and release them on release. So will the copy of the block made within `DoSomethingWith`. Assuming that copy eventually gets released there's no leak. It's pretty cool.

(Exception: if `Object` were declared `__block Someobject *Object`, along with the expected effect (removing the 'const' of the block's private reference, allowing the block to assign to `Object`), this autoretain behavior is also turned off. In that case retain/release is your responsibility again.)